# Programm is stuck while allocating space for a 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, string, malloc, allocation

Hey guys I have a problem, I i need to allocate space for a 2d array, but it somehow gets stuck. Afterwards it should get into a for loop, but it never gets there. Does someone has an idea why?

```
  int len = read_file("staedte.csv", staedte, laender, bewohner);

  char **resultat;
  int resultatzaehler = 0;
  resultat =(char **) malloc (100 * sizeof(char));
  if(resultat == NULL){
    printf("Malloc failed to allocate space");
    exit(1);
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    resultat[i] =(char *) malloc (100);
    if(resultat[i] == NULL){
      printf("Malloc failed to allocate spacce 2");
      exit(1);
    }
  }
```

Comment: How do you know where it is stuck?

Comment: `resultat =(char **) malloc (100 * sizeof(char));` -> `resultat =(char **) malloc (100 * sizeof(char*));`

Comment: resultat =(char **) malloc (100 * sizeof(char *)); ?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I tested it berforehand with some printf commands to see how far it goes, before it gets stuck. To the others: Thanks a lot that was the solution!:)

Comment: `resultat = malloc(100 * sizeof(*resultat))`

Comment: two losely related comments: 1.) do not cast the result of `malloc()` (in general, `void *`) **in C** 2.) Write your **code** in english only. I happen to understand this one, others  won't. As you never know who should understand it later, just use english.

Answer (score 1):

You should be allocating by using

```
resultat = (char**) malloc(100 * sizeof(char *))
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
resultat[i] = (char*) malloc(100 * sizeof(char))
}
```

Comment: Or better yet, `resultat = malloc(100 * sizeof *resultat);` and `resultat[i] = malloc(100);`

Comment: `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition.